# Flowchart Decision with more lines?

Tags: flowchart

[image]

Can i add more line in 1 decision like that picture? we can have more input in condition flowchart

for example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if( condition ){
        some process...
        some process...
        some process...
    } 
    else {
        some process...
        some process...
        some process...
        if(condition){
            some process...
            some process...
        }
    }
 }

some process...
some process...
some process...
```

or should we combine the line? like this picture?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to add another output than yes, no?

Comment: another input flow

Comment: You should be able to redirect another input flow to this condition. In the picture, it seems like there are already 3 inputs to the if condition. Adding more inputs should be possible.

Comment: ok, so we can add more line in the edge, not only in the corner, right?

Comment: Yes, this shape represents an if condition. Inputs should have nothing to do with the shape.

Comment: another question. can i combine lines? like picture 2

Comment: Yes, you can combine like this what matters is where the direction of the arrow is pointing to decide if it is an input or output. It doesn't matter where you put the arrows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, from Berk Ozturk answer:

Can i add more line in 1 decision like that picture? we can have more input in condition flowchart.

> You should be able to redirect another input flow to this condition.
> In the picture, it seems like there are already 3 inputs to the if
> condition. Adding more inputs should be possible.

can i combine lines? like picture 2

> Yes, you can combine like this what matters is where the direction of
> the arrow is pointing to decide if it is an input or output. It
> doesn't matter where you put the arrows.